# Warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast in C

Tags: c

I am getting the warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast in C. What is a cast? What should I do?

```
void UpdateElement(Console* console)
{
    DynamicVector* CostList=getAllCosts(console->ctrl);
    int i,n;
    printf("Give the position of the element you want to delete:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=n-1;i<getLen(CostList);i++)
    {
        Cost* c=(Cost*)getElementAtPosition(CostList,i);
        Cost* c2=AddCost(console); **//here I get the warning**
        update_an_element(console->ctrl,c,c2,i);
    }
}

Console* initConsole(Controller* ctrl)
{
    Console* console=(Console*)malloc(sizeof(Console));
    console->ctrl=ctrl;
    return console;
}

int createCost(Controller* ctrl, char* day, char* type, int sum)
{
    Cost* c=initCost(day,type,sum);
    save(ctrl->repo,c);
    return c; **//now here I get the warning**

}
```

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `Console`.

Comment: Are there prototypes for all functions used within UpdateElement()? Or are they all defined beforehand? If not then an implicit declaration will be generated, that returns an int.

Comment: YOu don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Could you post the declaration of the AddCost(…) function ? Seems it returns an int. You make it a pointer. That could be bad. See my answer.

Comment: @CucerzanRares: Maybe you should first write a question with all needed information instead of editing it every minute.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that:

```
AddCost(console);
```

is returning an integer which is then casted to a pointer (what the warning said).

Comment: AddCost returns because all the functions were void and I couldn't do Cost* c2-function() so I made AddCosts return.

Comment: When `AddCost()` returns an integer then you know where and why there is a warning.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is of type `Cost*` and the function `createCost` returns `int`. both are not compatible that's why the compiler complains about a missing cast, but you don't want to cast in this case.

Change the return type of that function to `Cost*`

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ assumes the return type is an integer unless specified by a header or it's declaration. You probably called a function that wasn't declared beforehand in the program and didn't have a header. It assumed it was an int and gave you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use

```
Cost* c2=(Cost*)AddCost(console);
```

But it may be unsafe since AddCost(...) is returning an other type.

As for the function

```
int createCost(Controller* ctrl, char* day, char* type, int sum)
```

It should be declared as

```
Cost* createCost(Controller* ctrl, char* day, char* type, int sum)
```

Why is it declared as int ?

Comment: It worked there. Now I am getting the warning in controller. I edited the post with the code.

Comment: @CucerzanRares Then you need `return (int)c;` but your program will probably crash. The function should probably be declared as `Cost* createCost(…)`.

Comment: In which way is the call of `AddCost(console)` connected to the function `createCost()`?

Comment: @flyingOwl It is not really connected. **There are two distinct warnings**. One because the return type of `createCost(…)` is `int` where, apparently, it should be `Cost*`. One because it seems that the return type of `AddCost(…)` is `int` and the OP assigns (cast) it to a pointer of type `Cost*`. The only connection between the two is that the both involve an improper conversion from `int` to `Cost*` and *vice versa*.

Comment: You're right, the OP has mixed up a lot casts and return types. I just wanted to add what I said above :)